# Why are divs overlapping? No floats, no absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, css-position

My `date-time-container` overlaps my upper elements of `welcome` and `weather` on vertical resize in mobile. I do not have any elements positioned absolute, I'm not using floats, I have made them block level elements, and also added clear: both, but they still overlap. Any idea on why this is occurring?

```css
  @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  body {
    max-width: 100vw;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #weather {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: auto;
    padding-right: 6%;
  }
  #loc-des {
    padding-right: 5%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
  }
  #welcome {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5% auto 0 auto;
    clear: both;
  }
  #main-container {
    max-width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  #date {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    clear: both;
  }
  #time {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
  }
  #date-time-container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    height: auto;
  }
  #time-container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    clear: both;
  }
```

```html
<h1 id="welcome"></h1>
<div id="weather">
  <div id="loc-des">
    <div id="location"></div>
    <div id="description"></div>
  </div>
  <h1 id="temp"></h1>
</div>

<main id="main-container">
  <section id="time-container">
    <section id="date-time-container">
      <h2 id="time">00:00</h2>
      <span id="date"></span>
    </section>

    <form action="https://www.duckduckgo.com/" target="_blank" autocomplete="off">
      <input type="search" name='q' id='search-bar' placeholder="search with duckduckgo ...">
    </form>
  </section>
```

Comment: This needs a runnable snippet [mcve].

Comment: At the minimum, you have to give them an empty space HTML char as content: `<h1>&nbsp;</h1>`. Without content, they'll have a computed height of `0px`.

Comment: Also note that your update does not show off the problem. It just renders something in which there is nothing "overlapping" anything else.

Answer (score 2):

It's because they don't have any content in it. 
If you add some contents between each tag(`<h1>` `<div>`), they will have their own space.

If you want to make elements with no content, 
you can add non-breaking space `&nbsp;` or give `padding` or `height`.